# Display just DD (Date) and SS (Seconds) in Infopath form

Tags: infopath

I'm using Infopath Designer 2013.

I need to create a unique ID of YYMMDDHHMMSS , with no symbols.

I have used "concat(Request Type, TodayYear(*substring(now(), 1, 4)*), TodayMonth(*substring(now(), 6, 2)*), TodayDate(*substring(now(), 9, 2)*), TodayHour(*substring(now(), 12, 5)*), TodayMinute, TodaySecond)"

However i cannot get the TodayMinute to display just MM and TodaySecond to display just SS with no symbols i.e. ":".

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Found a work around**

Year    - substring(now(), 1, 4)  - 1st letter return 4
Month   - substring(now(), 6, 2) - 6th letter return 2
Date    - substring(now(), 9, 2) - 9th letter return 2
Hour    - substring(now(), 12, 2) - 12th letter return 2
Minute  - substring(now(), 15, 2) - 15th letter return 2
Second  - substring(now(), 18, 2) - 18th letter return 2